# SQL 2016 low TPM with HammerDB-Test

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, windows-server, vmware

we have some trouble with a fresh installed MSSQL 2016 Server. The Server is a virtual VMware Machine using VMware's Best Practice. We have used the HammerDB-Tool to test TPM with TPC-C Standard. Unfortainly we only reach about 130.000 TPM. For a new Software, we have to reach a minimum with over 200.000 TPM.

By testing the drives separately we have seen, the SQL-Server is not using the full throughout for the Database-Drive (We have got a throughout with IOMeter of 1.2 GB/s).

*Parameters for IOMeter was: 12 Workers, 40000000 Sektors, # of Outstanding I/Os 16

Here are some fresh values:

**64 KiB; 0% Read; 0% Random**

> ```
> IOPS:                             14023  
> Total MBs per Second:               914.56 MBPS  
> Average I/O Response Time (ms):      13.75  
> Maximum I/O Response Time (ms):     161.40
> ```

**64 KiB; 50% Read; 0% Random**

> ```
> IOPS:                             14412  
> Total MBs per Second:               944 MBPS  
> Average I/O Response Time (ms):      13.30  
> Maximum I/O Response Time (ms):     413.59
> ```

**64 KiB; 100% Read; 0% Random**

> ```
> IOPS:                             14280   
> Total MBs per Second:               936.15 MBPS  
> Average I/O Response Time (ms):      13.44   
> Maximum I/O Response Time (ms):     173.95
> ```

*The Disk for Database is formatted with 64kb block size.*

Even CPU and Memory will not be used by 100% on the Server (While testing NUMA-Node1 only consumes 20% off their resources, NUMA-Node2 is below 5 %). *While running the HammerDB-test, the complete System uses about 5GB RAM*. The operating system and SQL-Service are configured by recommendations from Microsoft and HammerD-Tool.

So here are some other specs for the virtual machine:
5 HD-Drives (OS, DB, TempDB, Log, TempLog; Each drive is connected to the VM by separated Paravirtual SCSI-Controller )
2 Sockets with 6 CPU's each
128 GB RAM (110 are reserved for MSSQL)
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Operating System. If we run the HammerDB-Test with 10 virtual users, we got a CPU utilization as seen in the picture:
[image: CPU Utilization during HammerDB-Test]

Our virtual Environment and our SAN are connected by 8 Gb/s Fibre Channel Connections, each Host got 2 Connections to the SAN. Each Host has 32 physical CPUs with 2,6 GHz. On our SAN we have configured an SSD Raid10 LUN for storing Server and Data. For testing, we did not have other machines on the host so there is no over committing. Every config-parameter is set to high-performance starting at the BIOS-Level up to the Windows-Level.

*About the SQL-Configuration:
MAXDOP is set to 0. 'Optimize for Ad-Hoc workloads' is not enabled. 
'Lock pages in memory' is set to our SQL-Service-Account. We did not added Resource Governor policies to the server.*

We now had tested some various configurations with the CPU's, CPU per SOCKET, RAM and MAXDOP. In the table below you can see the Result as TPM for each tested configuration:

```
|  RAM | CPU/SOCKET | SOCKETS | MAXDOP |  TMP MIN. | TMP MAX. | TMP AVG. |  
|------|------------|---------|--------|-----------|----------|----------|   
|  128 |          8 |       1 |      0 |    88,000 |  100,000 |   93,000 |   
|  128 |          8 |       1 |      1 |    85,000 |   92,000 |   88,500 |
|  128 |          8 |       1 |      2 |    85,000 |   94,000 |   91,000 |
|  128 |          8 |       1 |      4 |    92,000 |  103,000 |   98,000 |
|  128 |          8 |       1 |      6 |    92,000 |  104,000 |   98,700 |
|  128 |          8 |       1 |      8 |    92,000 |  101,000 |   97,600 |
|------|------------|---------|--------|-----------|----------|----------|  
|  128 |         12 |       1 |      0 |   115,000 |  129,000 |  125,400 |   
|  128 |         12 |       1 |      1 |   127,000 |  142,000 |  134,300 |  
|  128 |         12 |       1 |      2 |   112,000 |  128,000 |  120,900 |  
|  128 |         12 |       1 |      4 |   114,000 |  128,000 |  120,800 |  
|  128 |         12 |       1 |      6 |   125,000 |  132,000 |  128,800 |  
|  128 |         12 |       1 |      8 |   125,000 |  138,000 |  131,300 |  
|  128 |         12 |       1 |     10 |   130,000 |  141,000 |  136,200 |  
|  128 |         12 |       1 |     12 |   123,000 |  133,000 |  128,100 |  
|------|------------|---------|--------|-----------|----------|----------|  
|  128 |          4 |       2 |      0 |    83,000 |   96,000 |   92,600 |
|  128 |          4 |       2 |      1 |    82,000 |   90,000 |   85,600 |
|  128 |          4 |       2 |      2 |    85,000 |   95,000 |   88,900 |
|  128 |          4 |       2 |      4 |    94,000 |  100,000 |   97,800 |
|  128 |          4 |       2 |      6 |    87,000 |  100,000 |   95,500 |
|  128 |          4 |       2 |      8 |    94,000 |  102,000 |   97,400 |
|------|------------|---------|--------|-----------|----------|----------|
|  128 |          6 |       2 |      0 |   115,000 |  129,000 |  119,500 |
|  128 |          6 |       2 |      1 |   117,000 |  142,000 |  129,300 |
|  128 |          6 |       2 |      2 |   120,000 |  128,000 |  125,200 |
|  128 |          6 |       2 |      4 |   125,000 |  134,000 |  128,800 |
|  128 |          6 |       2 |      6 |   123,000 |  131,000 |  129,100 |
|  128 |          6 |       2 |      8 |   125,000 |  138,000 |  132,800 |
|  128 |          6 |       2 |     10 |   125,000 |  136,000 |  131,900 |
|  128 |          6 |       2 |     12 |   129,000 |  141,000 |  134,700 |  
|------|------------|---------|--------|-----------|----------|----------|
|  128 |         16 |       1 |      0 |   111,000 |  128,000 |  119,300 |
|  128 |         16 |       1 |     12 |   129,000 |  138,000 |  134,900 |
|  128 |         16 |       1 |     16 |   122,000 |  133,000 |  127,900 |
|------|------------|---------|--------|-----------|----------|----------|
|   64 |         12 |       1 |      0 |   116,000 |  128,000 |  121,800 |
|   64 |         12 |       1 |      1 |   132,000 |  145,000 |  138,300 |
|   64 |         12 |       1 |      2 |   123,000 |  134,000 |  128,200 |
|   64 |         12 |       1 |      4 |   118,000 |  133,000 |  125,800 |
|   64 |         12 |       1 |      6 |   123,000 |  134,000 |  129,400 |
|   64 |         12 |       1 |      8 |   128,000 |  138,000 |  133,300 |
|   64 |         12 |       1 |     10 |   114,000 |  133,000 |  124,400 |
|   64 |         12 |       1 |     12 |   127,000 |  134,000 |  131,400 |
|------|------------|---------|--------|-----------|----------|----------|
```

I tested the server with sp_BlitzFirst now. But I know too less to interpret them correctly. By now I know CXPACKETS mean the CPU is idle. For all other values, I need your help :(

[image]
[image]

Looking at the Activity-Monitor, I see Locking have the highest impact on Wait-States. But at the Moment, in my opinion, there are two possibilities to reduce locking:
a) Speed-Up the overall Server-Performance, so a Page isn't locked when it needs to read again.
b) Change software. No real Option.
Here are the Results of the Activity-Monitor during the HammerDB-Test:

[image]

At this point, we don't know what's the problem with the Server. We have seen other Infrastructures with lower resources/power which can serve 200.000 TPM, only difference they use Hyper-V for virtualization.

Hope someone can help us.

Kind regards

Comment: Could you add the parameters for the IOMeter test? How were your disks formatted? (4kb, 8kb, **64kb** recommended) Did you set the **'Lock Pages in Memory'** policy to on? Are there any **Resource Governor** settings configured on your SQL Server instance? (turn them off) What is MAXDOP set to? Is the **'Optimize for Ad-Hoc workloads'** configured? (Turn it off) How much memory is actually being used during the execution of HammerD?

Comment: Hey, I added the information in the Query in italic-font.

Comment: What were the results with 50/50 and 100/0? Anywhere near 1000 MB/s?

Comment: How many other VM's are hosted on the physical box? Are you overcomitting resources? What does the "actual vm speed in mhz" performance counter show? Are your boxes configured for high performance in the bios?

Comment: Seeing as you can accomplish nearly 1000 MB/s throughput with the IOMeter tool, but not when using HammerDB, it must have something to do with the way these tools access the disks. IOMeter naturally just creates a file on a disk and bashes away, without having to ask anybody else for permission, whereas HammerDB is accessing a database. So you have SQL Server (sqlserver.exe) inbetween, which negotiates how the database access is performed. While @TomV 's hint is good, we can still observe that the server can perform when only running IOMeter.

Comment: VMware distributes resources in a round robin fashion. SQL Server does a similar job under the hood (sys.dm_os_schedulers). There are situations where the distribution of VMware resources costs more than the actual resources distributed, especially when having to run parallel query tasks in SQL Server. Quick Test: Run HammerDB while the SQL Server instance is set to MAXDOP = 8 / 4 / 2 / 1 and observe if your findings change.

Comment: Also, there is no guarantee this box can handle 200K TPM because a "similar box" does. How did you determine this box should be able to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You've written a lot of stuff, but here's your main question:

**Why are my TPC benchmark numbers not what I expect?**

To find the answer for that, check your SQL Server's wait stats while your workload is running. They're stored in sys.dm_os_wait_stats, but only as a cumulative number, so I wrote [sp_BlitzFirst](https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/) to do differentials for you during heavy workloads. Run it like this:

```
sp_BlitzFirst @ExpertMode = 1, @Seconds = 30
```

And you'll capture a 30-second sample of your server's waits during the test. Look at the wait stats section to identify what your server's waiting on - and feel free to post a picture of that portion of the results to get additional help.

The bottleneck may not be storage or CPU. Wait stats are the key to finding it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information in the documentation section of the HammerDB site that can help you, in particular the SQL Server OLTP best practice guide. There are a number of basic checks that you need to make to identify the bottleneck.
1. Remember the TPM reported is an average so when you run the HammerDB transaction monitor during a test does it ramp-up and reach a straight and steady line or does it have 'peaks and troughs' - if it is the latter then this is the first indication of a bottleneck and your workload is stopping and starting.
2. During a test run the SQL Server Management Studio - right click on the top line and select Activity Monitor - in this scroll down to Resource Waits - what is the top wait category and the wait time? 3. Run the scripts provided by FusionIO referenced in the best practice guide that drill down on these wait events to detail where the system is waiting. Now take steps to resolve that bottleneck - for example if "Logging" is the top event follow the guide to optimize the log and then consider moving it to device that can support faster write throughput. Continue the process of test, identify and resolve - when your CPU is near to fully utilized this will be peak performance.